# How to show exceptions from controller on the same page?

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee, spring-mvc, exception

First of all I want to start by saying that I am new to both Spring and Spring MVC.

Here is my question:

I am using Spring 3.0 for doing this.
Event: User clicks a link on my homepage.
Output: I have to show an error message saying "Service not available" on my homepage (in case an error is thrown by a controller).

Currently I just want to simulate this scenario without any business logic so I want to have a link on my homepage and when I click it, it should go to the controller which will always throw an exception. All I need to do is to catch this exception and show it on my Jsp page as "Service not available".

I have searched online but could not find a step by step tutorial to do this... Please guide me.

Answer (score 2):

You may also want to look at the [Documentation about handling exceptions](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-exceptionhandlers).

The default strategy, using annotations, is based on `@ExceptionHandler`: you may want to google this one if you want to learn with examples.

Comment: Thats great! This is exactly what I was looking for. But I cannot show the error on the JSP page...

Comment: @Soni - yes you can: you just have to add an Exception-typed parameter to your annotated method (Spring will populate it for you when handling the exception), then inject it into your model as usual.

Answer (score 1):

> All I need to do is to catch this exception and show it on my Jsp page as "Service not available".

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/homepage", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView doStuff() 
{
    try
    {
       throw new MyException();
       //return new ModelAndView("myJsp");
    }
    catch (MyException e)    
    {
        return new ModelAndView("myJsp", "exception", e);       
    }
}
```

jsp:

```
...
<c:if test="${not empty exception}">Service not avilable</c:if>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for showing me the direction. I was able to throw exception but ${not empty exception} doesnt seem to work, any cues?

Comment: @Soni Mishra: what means "not work" - does it always print "Service not aviable" or never print it? -- In order to understand the problem a bit more, you could always print the exception variable (`${exception}`), this may help to understand whether the variable is not set or the if constraint is not working as expected.

Comment: ${not empty exception} prints nothing. Sorry for late reply. I will try with ${exception} and see if it works.

Comment: @Soni Mishra: try `<c:out value="${exception}" />` (outside of the if block) to check *(poor mans debugging)* if the variable is correct populated.